# Create/call a function within a function

Tags: java, processing

Is it possible to create a function within another function ? If not, how should I define a function to be able to call it within another one ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You could  declare a class containing a function inside the method, then instantiate that class, but I highly recommend not doing so...

Comment: Use `private` methods instead. What you want isn't possible in java.

Comment: Actually, this is possible in Java - to make this possible, Sun introduced local and anonymous classes many years ago in JDK 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can declare them immediately inside your method, but you can declare a class inside your method (a *local* class), with a function in that class, or you can define an *anonymous* class in an expression.

This feature was added in Java 1.1 to support this type of function defined inside a method.

Example:

```
public class X {
    interface Func {
        int plus(int x);
    }

    public void myFunc() {
        final int z = 3;

        myOtherFunc(new Func() {  // Anonymous class declaration
            public int plus(int x) {
                return z + x;
            }
        });
    }

    public void myOtherFunc(Func f) {
         System.out.println(f.plus(8));
    }
}
```

In Java version 8 and higher you can declare this type of anonymous class that only implements one method in an even nicer way:

```
myOtherFunc(x -> z + x);
```